# How to clear state of one notebook without affecting other notebook using command in Azure Databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have 3 notebook pipelines running in parallel on same cluster, I want to know if there is any way to clear all the scala variables and spark DFs of one notebook without affecting other notebook? I tried spark.close() but it clears state of other two notebooks. I know that detaching notebook will clear state but how to do it using commands?And I also want to know if there are any ways to call gc and clear the garbage.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your code inside a wrapper kind of object so that if anything goes wrong your can re declare that object.